# CAKeyframeAnimation - animate along segment of a path

Tags: ios, core-animation

I'm trying to animate an object along a specific segment of a path using CAKeyframeAnimation.  Is this possible?

Think of a path as parameterized between 0 and 1, which is what an animation will typically run on (from the start of the curve to the end of the curve).  Is there a way I can run an animation, say, from .25 to .75 of this path?

I know I can offset an animation with the 'offset' parameter, but this only adjusts the start position and still loops around to the end of the curve.  It also doesn't correctly obey the CAMediaTiming function, if set.

Comment: It's been a few years, but in case you're still looking for a answer: I [answered another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48723605/608157) about how to "animate [...] along a part of a bezier path" before finding this question.