# How to remove delay on start and end of animateKeyframes animation - Swift UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Is there a way to remove the delay on start and end of the animateKeyframes animation?

As you can see there is a slight delay before the animation starts; after tapping on the `Animate` button and also at the end of the animation. What I would like to be able to do is start the animation as soon as the `Animate` button is tapped since this is meant to provide feedback to the user.

Is this the normal behavior when using `animateKeyframes` animations with the `calculationModeCubic`?  Is there a way to make the animation starts as soon as the button is tapped?

[image]

Sorry about the misspelling error (Aniamate).

### Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func startAnimation(_ sender: Any) {
    addMyView()
    
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 3.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.calculationModeCubic], animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.myView!.center =  CGPoint(x: self.pointA.center.x, y: self.pointA.center.y)
        })
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.2, relativeDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.myView!.center =  CGPoint(x: self.pointB.center.x + 55, y: self.pointB.center.y - 5 )
            self.myView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.75, y: 0.75)
        })
        
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.4, relativeDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.myView!.center =  CGPoint(x: self.pointB.center.x, y: self.pointB.center.y)
            self.myView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        })
    }, completion: { _ in
        self.myView?.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}

func addMyView(){
    myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: pointA.center.x - 25, y: pointA.center.y - 25, width: 50, height: 50))
    myView?.backgroundColor = .blue
    myView?.layer.cornerRadius = myView!.frame.height / 2
    view.addSubview(myView!)
}
```

Comment: Try styling and adding the view once with `.isHidden` set to `true`. Then unhide the view before the animation and reset its frame and re-hide it on completion.

Comment: I tried hiding it and not showing it until the first keyframe animation but I get the same exact behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Does it work as desired with any other animation options, like `calculationModeCubicPaced`?

Comment: The `calculationModeCubicPaced` seems to be the only one where the animation starts moving right-way but I cannot tweak it to get the same effect as with the `calculationModeCubic`

Comment: Getting animations precise with frameworks like this that blend animations together requires trial and error. Just to be clear, you added the subview before the button tap and then unhid it on tap, correct?

Comment: You can also string together multiple `CATransaction` blocks and execute them effectively at the same time. Keyframe animations are not the only way to achieve this. In fact, I've had more luck with `CATransaction` than any other API when animating multiple things in sync.

Comment: Correct. I created and hid `myView` in ViewDidLoad and then just unhide it before animating it. How hard would it be to create the same throwing effect using `CATransaction`? I just went with `animateKeyframes` because of how easy it is to create a three-point curve animation with `calculationModeCubic`

Comment: `CATransaction` is just as easy as, if not easier than, what you're doing now. But you may have more luck with key-frame animations. You just need to use the one that gives you what you want.

Comment: Would you create three points as I'm doing now to create the curve? Or how would you create the curve effect?

Comment: You can animate along bezier paths, for example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252678/animate-a-uiview-along-a-part-of-a-bezier-path

Comment: Ok, I'll give it try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to keep tweaking the `withRelativeStartTime:` and the `relativeDuration:` parameters.

```
@IBAction func startAnimation(_ sender: Any) {
    addMyView()
      UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.calculationModeCubic], animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.myView!.center =  CGPoint(x: self.pointA.center.x, y: self.pointA.center.y)
        })
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.9, animations: {
            self.myView!.center =  CGPoint(x: self.pointB.center.x + 75, y: self.pointB.center.y - 50 )
            self.myView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.75, y: 0.75)
        })
        
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.1, relativeDuration: 0.7, animations: {
            self.myView!.center =  CGPoint(x: self.pointB.center.x, y: self.pointB.center.y)
            self.myView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.3, y: 0.3)
        })
    }, completion: { _ in
        self.myView?.removeFromSuperview()
    })      

}
```